# Why is my SQL instance suddenly increasing i/o

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following query:

```
WITH CTE AS (    
    -- Acknowledged: false
    SELECT TOP 5
        dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDetailID,
        dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDateTime,
        dbo.Vehicule.Name,
        dbo.Vehicule.PhoneNumber,
        -- (X.value('(//ContextName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') + ' : ' + X.value('(//EnumValueName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) AS DisplayName,
        (dbo.Alert.DisplayName + ' ('+ X.value('(//EnumValueName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') +')') AS DisplayName,
        (CASE WHEN dbo.AlertDetail.AckTime IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS Acknowledged,
        dbo.AlertDetail.AckTime,
        (CASE WHEN dbo.AlertDetail.AckPhoneNumber IS NOT NULL THEN dbo.AlertDetail.AckPhoneNumber ELSE dbo.AlertDetail.AckMachineName + '\' + dbo.AlertDetail.AckUserName END) AS AckPhoneNumber,
        dbo.AlertDetail.SafeProtectCustomInfo
    FROM dbo.Alert
    INNER JOIN dbo.AlertDetail ON (dbo.AlertDetail.AlertID = dbo.Alert.AlertID
        AND dbo.Alert.CompanyID = @CompanyID
        AND dbo.AlertDetail.AckTime IS NULL)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Vehicule ON (dbo.AlertDetail.TrackedVehiculeID = dbo.Vehicule.VehiculeID
        AND GpsBoxType IN (@GpsBoxType1,@GpsBoxType2)
        AND dbo.Vehicule.CompanyID = @CompanyID
        AND dbo.Vehicule.RowEnabled = 1)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(dbo.AlertDetail.Context, 'encoding="utf-8"', '') AS XML)) AS T(X)
    WHERE dbo.Alert.RowEnabled = 1
        AND CHARINDEX('SerializableContextAlertDetail', dbo.AlertDetail.Context) > 0
        AND dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDateTime > @MinDate
    ORDER BY dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDateTime DESC
    
    UNION
    
    -- Acknowledged: true
    SELECT TOP 5
        dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDetailID,
        dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDateTime,
        dbo.Vehicule.Name,
        dbo.Vehicule.PhoneNumber,
        -- (X.value('(//ContextName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') + ' : ' + X.value('(//EnumValueName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) AS DisplayName,
        (dbo.Alert.DisplayName + ' ('+ X.value('(//EnumValueName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') +')') AS DisplayName,
        (CASE WHEN dbo.AlertDetail.AckTime IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS Acknowledged,
        dbo.AlertDetail.AckTime,
        (CASE WHEN dbo.AlertDetail.AckPhoneNumber IS NOT NULL THEN dbo.AlertDetail.AckPhoneNumber ELSE dbo.AlertDetail.AckMachineName + '\' + dbo.AlertDetail.AckUserName END) AS AckPhoneNumber,
        dbo.AlertDetail.SafeProtectCustomInfo
    FROM dbo.Alert
    INNER JOIN dbo.AlertDetail ON (dbo.AlertDetail.AlertID = dbo.Alert.AlertID
        AND dbo.Alert.CompanyID = @CompanyID
        AND dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDateTime >= @AlertDateTimeStart
        AND dbo.AlertDetail.AckTime IS NOT NULL)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Vehicule ON (dbo.AlertDetail.TrackedVehiculeID = dbo.Vehicule.VehiculeID
        AND GpsBoxType IN (@GpsBoxType1,@GpsBoxType2)
        AND dbo.Vehicule.CompanyID = @CompanyID
        AND dbo.Vehicule.RowEnabled = 1)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(dbo.AlertDetail.Context, 'encoding="utf-8"', '') AS XML)) AS T(X)
    WHERE dbo.Alert.RowEnabled = 1
        AND CHARINDEX('SerializableContextAlertDetail', dbo.AlertDetail.Context) > 0
        AND dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDateTime > @MinDate
    ORDER BY dbo.AlertDetail.AlertDateTime DESC
)
SELECT TOP 5 CTE.* FROM CTE
ORDER BY CTE.Acknowledged ASC, CTE.AlertDateTime DESC
```

Most of the time it works very well and responds in a few ms.

But sometimes, the SQL instance is doing so much I/O for this query that the whole server seems to be not responding.

The only way I have found to go back to normal is to run the following command:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Then performance will return back to normal for the next execution of the statement.

What could be the root cause of the problem?

Note that he execution plan gives the following warning (in french, sorry):

```
La conversion de type dans l'expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),[Expr1018],0)) peut affecter « CardinalityEstimate » dans le choix du plan de requête; 
La conversion de type dans l'expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),[Expr1017],0)) peut affecter « CardinalityEstimate » dans le choix du plan de requête; 
La conversion de type dans l'expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),[Expr1042],0)) peut affecter « CardinalityEstimate » dans le choix du plan de requête; 
La conversion de type dans l'expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),[Expr1041],0)) peut affecter « CardinalityEstimate » dans le choix du plan de requête
```

> ***Translation:**
> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),[Expr10xx],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice*

I have added the query plans as per the request in the comments:

- query plan when the performance is [good](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byo6CuXlc).
- query plan when the performance is [bad](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkVR3d7xq).

Following are new details per the request in the comments:

- Host : RAM 10GB, CPU 3GHz, HDD 4x100GB
- Table : About 2 million rows (1948601)
- I'm not sure the actual plan would help as I slightly modified the query by adding:

> OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@CompanyID UNKNOWN))

Comment: You likely have a bad plan for the query, either caused by parameter sniffing or outdated statistics. To debug, try and [get an execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) for the well-performing query and for the poor-performing one.

Comment: What is the configuration of the server this query is running on? Hardware, Memory, Disks, CPUs, ...? How big is the database and/or the tables involved? Millions of rows? A couple of thousand? 200 GB, 700 GB, 1 TB, ....? Seeing as you are observing I/O you might want to consider increasing RAM (`max server memory (MB)`). Just a hunch. The more details we have the better we can assist.

Comment: Thank you for the execution plans.

Comment: Parallelism seems to be missing from bad plan. Is it possible to post actual execution plan?

Comment: Due to warning of execution plan, you should determine where the implicit conversion is happening. Implicit Conversion is a performance killer. First check your condition and check if operands have the same datatype. It may be a root cause or not. But removing them help a lot.

Comment: We would need the actual plan without the `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@CompanyID UNKNOWN))`. Without that we are going to have a hard time guessing. If the `OPTION ...`  is in production, then that could be the issue.